# Deletion of [tag:wrong]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I believe that the [wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wrong) should be deleted. It is not description and I do not see how it could be applied to any question.

Comment: It's pretty amazing that you propose the tag for deletion and at the same time, put it on this question.